# Django form POST request issue

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create an option menu input field which takes input from a POST request. My python code calls the database using a variable with the same value as the input field. Where the name is the value of the input field.

I am having issues getting the data back to the Django application, I am also having trouble seeing the output in the VS code terminal and the browser console.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Navbar, Hero
from django.http import JsonResponse
from core.forms import BuildForm



def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BuildForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            nav = form.cleaned_data['Nav']
            hero = form.cleaned_data['Hero']
            my_object = get_object_or_404(Navbar, id=nav)
            my_object2 = get_object_or_404(Hero, id=hero)
            return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'my_object': my_object})

    else:
        form = BuildForm()
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
  from django import forms

class BuildForm(forms.Form):
    Nav = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    Hero = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

index.html

```
   {% extends 'core/base.html' %}
    
    {% block title %}Welcome To Atom{% endblock %}
    
    {% block content %}
    
    
    
    <div class="choosepage">
        <h1>Choose a page to view</h1>
     
    
    <form>
      
        {{ form.as_p }}
    
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    
    </form>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static %}
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"></link>
            <title>Atom | {% block title %} {% endblock %}   </title>
        </head>
    <body>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
    
    <script src="{% static 'js/form.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me how do I check that there is data in the /nav/ and /hero/ variables from the index function in the views.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all mydify your  tag. In your views file you are using: if request.method == 'POST', so your form should look like: `<form method="post">`. Btw you have to put  `{% csrf_token %}` in the beginning of your form tag

There are few methods to check the data in your example:
1 add your variable values into your view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BuildForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            nav = form.cleaned_data['Nav']
            hero = form.cleaned_data['Hero']
            my_object = get_object_or_404(Navbar, id=nav)
            my_object2 = get_object_or_404(Hero, id=hero)
            return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'my_object': my_object, 'nav': nav, 'hero':hero})

    else:
        form = BuildForm()
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'form': form})
```

And render it via `{{nav}}` and `{{hero}}` in your template.

2. You can use JS/AJAX request. To do that you should modify your urls.py file for your view and write a simple ajax request, all the response data returned with your ajax request, you can output via `console.log(response.nav)` or `alert(response.nav)`

var url = '/core/';
var data = {
nav: yourform-nav,
hero: yourform-hero
csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken}
$.ajax({
url:url,
type: 'POST',
data:data,
}).done(function(response){console.log(response.nav); console.log(response.hero)})

3. If it is your local project, you can use print function in your view.
4. You can also use logging. to da that you should modify your settings.py.